# mongodb-java-driver how to group multiple fields?

Tags: mongodb-java

Does mongodb-java-driver group only support one field? e.g.

```
group("$customerId", sum("totalQuantity", "$quantity"), avg("averageQuantity", "$quantity"))
```

if group with multi fields, how to implement? e.g.

```
"_id":{platform:"$platform",screen_name:"$screen_name"}
```

I tried below manner, but it does not work

```
group("{platform:\"$platform\",screen_name:\"$screen_name\"}", sum("totalQuantity", "$quantity")
```

So how to support multiple group field in mongodb-java-driver?